# Find All in the current document in VS2008

Tags: visual-studio-2008, shortcut

Is there any shortcut available in VS2008 to directly switch to Find All window with current document selected.

Ctrl+Shift+F opens the Find All window with last option selected

Answer (score 0):

Find All References is `Shift + F12` or `CTRL + K, R`.

Comment: That was not what the OP asked for.

Answer (score 0):

`Ctrl+F` has always done current document for me, where `Ctrl+Shift+F` is the Find in Files dialog

Comment: Well, I think that is what the OP already knows - Ctrl+F does not open the find window in "Find All" mode, Ctrl-Shift+F opens in "Find All" mode, but not necessarily for the current document.

Comment: What is the difference between the Find window (Ctrl+F) and the Find in All window (Ctrl+Shift+F in Current Document) mode.

The only different I can think, is you can have the results put into a Find tab

Answer (score 0):

`Ctrl+Shift+F` + `Tab` + 4x `Cursor-Up` should do the trick.